# Any suggestions to why this loop isn't executing?

Tags: c++, for-loop, conditional-statements

I have written the function below, which groups charterers together before encountering a space and saves each group in a vector, once a space is encountered it should look for another group and do the same thing over and over!

My debugging so far indicates that the for loop within the if statement is not executing for some reason.

```
char const* MathematicaLib::IsThisAnEquation(char const* equation){

    // execute PEMDAS here

    vector <char const*> SeperatedValues;
    char *TempGH = "";

    int temp = 0;
    int SOG = 0; //start of group

    //cout << equation[2] << endl; // used to test whether the funcion is reading the input parameter


    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(equation); j++)
    {           
        if (isspace(equation[j])) {
            //cout << "processing" << endl; // used to confirm that its reading values until a space is encountered
            for (int n = SOG; n < j - 1; n++){ 
                TempGH[temp] = equation[n];
                temp++;
                SOG = j + 1; //skip charecter
                cout << "test"; //this does not print out meaning that the loop dosen't execute
            }

            temp = 0;
            SeperatedValues.push_back(TempGH);  
        }           
    }

    for (unsigned int p = 0; p < SeperatedValues.size(); p++){ // used for debugging only
        cout << SeperatedValues[p] << endl;
        cout << "This should be reading the vector contents" << endl;
    }

    return "";
}// end of IsThisAnEquation
```

Assume that the value I am passing to the function is "123 1", also assume that the first character of the parameter is never a space. This means that when a space is detected then **n == 0** AND **j-1 == 2**  (j-1 indicates the end of the group of characters while n = the start) the loop should cause the characters in position 0 to 2 (123) to be pushed into the vector, **thus j is not == 0 or -1.**

The loop is not directly embedded under the first for loop rather it is under the if statement, shouldn't this force to only execute if the condition within the if statment is true? rather than follow the rules of embedded loops execution?

Any suggestions to why this loop isn't executing?

I have reviewed the code over and over to spot any logical errors, but I couldn't find any so far!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: The variable `TempGH` points to a string literal of zero length (technically an array of one character, the string terminator), the expression `TempGH[temp] = equation[n]` will give you *undefined behavior*: Both because you are trying to modify a string literal which is *constant*, and then because you might be out of bounds. If you work with strings in C++ then use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (then you can do things like `TempHG += equation[n]`)..

Comment: Are you sure that `isspace` works correctly?

Comment: for this kind of debugging `cout`s it is better to put a `std::endl`. It might well be that the `cout` is actually executed and you just dont see it because the stream is never flushed

Comment: @Aboudi *I have reviewed the code over and over to spot any logical errors, but I couldn't find any so far!* -- Programmers use something called a "debugger".  Many times we can't just eyeball logical errors and attempt to run the program "in our heads" trying to remember variables, their values, etc..  It's time for you to learn to use this valuable tool.

Comment: @Aboudi *Any suggestions to why this loop isn't executing?* -- It's not executing because the middle condition `n < j - 1` in the `for` evaluates to `false` on the first iteration.  There is no other reason.  Now, why is it false? -- that's what debugging is about.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, please see my update, well its definitely false because it doesn't execute but according to what I have mentioned in my update, it indicates why I think it should not be false. I took on-board what you said any ways and changed the parameter J but still no result!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, TempGH[temp] = equation[n]; dosent cause undefined behaviour, it points to the first character within the input parameter (which should never be a space), or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Aboudi It is undefined behavior because you are changing a string-literal.  This was already pointed out by a previous comment: `{ char *temp="abc"; temp[0] = 'x';}`  Run that little bit of code, and don't be surprised if it crashes.

Comment: @FedeWar Yes, I have placed a few cout statements right after the first loop, they stop executing when the space is reached!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, Thanks I didn't know that attempting to change it will cause undefined behaviour. I have temporarily removed this from my code and will deal with it later, but according to my update dosen't that suggest that the middle condition should be true and not false?

Answer (score 0):

My bad  `if (isspace(equation[j])` was the root of all evil, this condition was not being met because `std::cin >> equation` does not register spaces, replacing it with this `std::getline(std::cin, equation);`  managed to solve the problem, the for loop now executes.

Thanks to  @PaulMcKenzie and  @Joachim Pileborg for pointing out the issue of modifying string literals.

Sorry I didn't mention that I was passing the parameter through `std::cin>>` !

Comment: @FedeWar, thanks, I thought it was working but appears otherwise.